# How to make a sun in Blender?

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, texturing, blender-internal-render-engine, light

How do I make a nice sun in Blender? I am not looking to change a lamp into the sun, I am looking for an actual sun that can be seen in my scene.

Back in high school, I had a project on making a sun but I forgot how it's done. Blender has had a dramatic change since then anyway so any help on making a sun in blender would be nice thank you.

Also, if there are different processes to doing this in Blender render vs Blender Cycles please, I would appreciate both ways explained.

Comment: It could be quite easy or very complex ... "A nice sun" is bit vague... What kind of scene are you doing? The sun in a landscape or a representation of the sun with all of its sunspots and storms illuminating planets around it...? Can you provide a reference image of what you are after?

Comment: I am Talking about a sun in a scene say like a sky and some ground and a sun in the sky in daytime. i hope  this helps

Comment: have you a link to any reference image for your particular case? that would help anyone to find a better hint...

Comment: I have one from highschool but its not that great ill get it

Comment: I would simply  use an HDRI image because it is the most realistic, though they don't allow you to reposition the sun.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After a bit of research and tweaking I came up with a simple answer to my own question using the blender internal render.

I used a UV sphere and change the materials a bit to create a good looking sun for my scene.

The material settings for my sun are outlined in red below:[image]

Answer (score 25):

I would do this in Cycles using volumetric lighting.

[image]

Here's the basic setup: just one light on a landscape.

[image]

Then add a cube around the scene with some volume scatter and volume absorption as materials.

[image]

[image]

for the background you can use a color ramp like this:

[image]

Comment: Ideally you'd want the world texture to follow the sun and change as it becomes higher. Its interesting because you are supplementing the world color, which is supposed to represent atmosphere, with volumetric atmosphere. I guess one is more distant than the other. Great effect though.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Cycles World Texture Sky]

Here's an alternate approach that uses makes use of some simple texture gradients for a procedural sky in the world texture. The "sun disk" part is what you're interested in here. This takes advantage of additive color mixing and color ramp gradients. It takes a bit of tweaking to get right, but has some potential. Since the sun disk size can be tricky to get right, it may be improved by adding a math node to it between the gradient and color ramp to improve the fall-off control. (Perhaps multiply or power?)