# Atmospheric Lighting: Am I doing it wrong?

Tags: light, volumetrics

http://www.imgur.com/a/AXp3H

At the time I have posted these images and attempted atmospheric lighting, I have attempted to follow alongside a tutorial out of Blenderguru.com, but the results were much different from what the narrator expressed. Particularly, he used 2.71, while I am using 2.77 RC1 (Not even going to bother getting RC2, just waiting for the full release.), so there is bound to be plenty wrong with what I am doing.

Further in particular, he used a density setting of .1, while I had to use .0005, and the spot lamp I used needed a strength setting of approximately 500000, just for the halo rays. You cannot even see the world background around, it just goes completely dark. Am I doing something wrong here, besides using a version of blender completely different from what the tutorial had at the time?

Here is the blend:
http://www.pasteall.org/blend/41034

Comment: maybe related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38830/volumetric-spot-light-with-cycles/38833#38833

Comment: Using volume scatter on the world settings cancels out the background indeed. As an alternative you can use an object as a domain see: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40987/how-to-make-a-sun-in-blender/41307#41307

Comment: Thanks, users. http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40987/how-to-make-a-sun-in-blender/41307#41307 This worked a little more than the other one, using a cube instead of crippling the world settings. I am not sure how to use Density and Anisotropy to get thicker cast shadows, but I am working on it. Any ideas?