# Cycles Volume: Dynamic Step Size?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, volumetrics

I've been thinking about Cycles' Volume Scatter, and how AMAZINGLY SLOW rendering volumes are. Especially so if you have both a very large, very far away volume (like clouds)in your scene and a very detailed, very close volume (like ground fog)... and you're rendering an animation, so you can't do many separate renders for each frame and still patch it together in any reasonable amount of time.

Is there a way to make the heterogenous volume's STEP SIZE increase with distance from the camera/viewport?
How would this affect render times?
If there's no option to do this, then how easy would it be to implement, and how to people do things like this as of now?

Comment: If you use volume scatter on the world volume settings, it will take much longer to render than if you choose to have the scattering as a domain object. See this to get an idea: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/41307/1853