# How do I add a sun to the background without a texture?

Tags: materials, node-editor, world

[image: The current setup]

I'm trying to get rid of the extra texture in the world material to save on memory that I can use on other things than a white dot in the sky.

Comment: Add a cicle in the scene and kame it an emitter, or add a light http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40987/how-to-make-a-sun-in-blender/41307#41307

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is kinde of easy to make it but it's harder to control.[image]

Remember that you might get a sun mirror becuas of the power node. You can remove it with two more math nodes. One grater than 0 and use that to remove all negative values and it will remove one sun.
[image]