# Blender Sunset Scene

Tags: scene

How to create  sunset scene in blender 2.78? I need sunset scene such:

1. animated
2. without using any image captured sunset
3. look like this:

[image: Sunset]

All videos and tutorials creates sunset using sunset images. But how to create sunset without any image and animated?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/41307/1853

Comment: @YusaMac205 the OP states "without using any image captured sunset"

Comment: Tutorial in                                                         blender.stackexchange.com/a/41307/1853 makes sun in blender but sun is not animated.